# remove repeated rows on matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a $n\times 2$ matrix as the following example

```
1   21
3   23
3   23
1   21
6   24
6   24
6   24
```

and I need obtain a new matrix (with 2 columns) with non reapeated rows, which in this example is

```
1   21
3   23
6   24
```

How I can do this on matlab?

Comment: `help unique` will answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the [unique](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function in Matlab does exactly what you want to.